# Duvida no meu codigo nao esta imprimindo de forma correta

Tags: python

pergunta: Usando o arquivo texto notas_estudantes.dat escreva um programa que calcula a nota mínima e máxima de cada estudante e imprima o nome de cada aluno junto com a sua nota máxima e mínima. arquivo:

```
jose 10 15 20 30 40
pedro 23 16 19 22
suzana 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17
gisela 12 28 21 45 26 10
joao 14 32 25 16 89
```

meu codigo:

```
arq=open('notas_estudantes.dat','r')
conteudo=arq.readlines()
arq.close()
for item in conteudo:
    lista=item.split()
    lista.sort()
    print(lista[-1],':','Nota Maxima:',lista[-2],'Nota Minima:',lista[0])
```

quando vou imprimir dar isso:

```
jose : Nota Maxima: 40 Nota Minima: 10
pedro : Nota Maxima: 23 Nota Minima: 16
suzana : Nota Maxima: 9 Nota Minima: 11
gisela : Nota Maxima: 45 Nota Minima: 10
joao : Nota Maxima: 89 Nota Minima: 14
```

os outros estao todos corretos porem quando chega a parte de suzana ele nao dar o resultado correto, gostaria de saber se é algo erro do pyhton ou foi eu mesmo que errei algo no codigo.

Comment: A minha questão é porquê o sort ? Para o objetivo indicado não é necessário o `sort` e naturalmente seria menos eficiente ordenar a lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dito antes, você tem que tomar cuidado com os tipos que está lidando em seus containers.  Eu fiz uma outra implementação pra gerar o resultado esperado pra você.  Eu retirei os nomes, e converti o restante para inteiros, ficando mais fácil retirar o max e min da lista.

```
arq = open('arquivo.dat','r')
conteudo = arq.readlines()
arq.close()
for item in conteudo:
    lista = item.split()
    aluno = lista[0]
    del lista[0]
    notas = list(map(int, lista))
    print('Aluno: {}, Nota max: {}, Nota Min: {}'.format(aluno, max(notas), min(notas)))
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

O seu código que está errado, quando você realiza a chamada do método `sort()` o mesmo ordena a lista de forma crescente porém os dados na lista retornada pelo método `split()` são do tipo `string`, ou seja, quando o método `sort()` é invocado ele verifica `caractere por caractere` do dado, veja:

```
>>> conteudo = "suzana 8 22 17 14 32 17 24 21 2 9 11 17"
>>> dados = conteudo.split(" ")
['suzana', '8', '22', '17', '14', '32', '17', '24', '21', '2', '9', '11',
>>> dados.sort()
['11', '14', '17', '17', '17', '2', '21', '22', '24', '32', '8', '9', 'suzana']
```

Percebeu ?
`'11'` vem antes de `"2"` pois ele verifica `caractere por caractere`. O que você poderia fazer para resolver é:

```
arquivo = open("notas_estudantes.dat", "r")
conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()
for item in conteudo:
    lista = item.split()
    nome = lista.pop(0)
    lista.sort(key = int)
    print(nome, ":", "Nota Máxima:", lista[-2], "Nota Minima:", lista[0])
```

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: Que isso, estamos aqui pra isso. Qualquer dúvida não hesite em postar aqui no Stack.

Answer (score 4):

Você está tratando as notas como *strings*, daí quando você faz a ordenação o Python coloca "1", "10", na frente de "2", "4" etc. Neste caso a melhor solução é trabalhar com elas como um formato numérico.

```
# ...
for item in conteudo:
    lista = item.split()  # converte a linha lida em uma array
    nome = lista.pop(0)  # retira o nome de dentro do array
    notas = [int(i) for i in lista]  # cria um novo array com o que sobrou de
                                     # 'lista', convertendo cada elemento em um
                                     # número inteiro.

    # por fim, usa min() e max() para obter os valores agora que eles são números.
    print(nome, ':', 'Nota Maxima:', max(notas), 'Nota Minima:', min(notas))
```

Claro que esta é UMA solução, mas como você quer saber as notas máxima e mínima (quer tratá-las como valores) preferi a abordagem mais "numérica".

Comment: muito obrigado!